# Grouping rows in sql query with different tables

Tags: sql-server, northwind

how can i write a query that shows a result like below

```
1          Beverages           NULL                     NULL          
1          Beverages           Chai                     Exotic Liquids
1          Beverages           Cheng                    Exotic Liquids
1          Dairy Products      NULL                     NULL
1          Beverages           Gorgonzola Telino        Tokyo Traders
1          Beverages           Geitost                  Tokyo Traders
1          Beverages           Gudbrandsdalsost         Tokyo Traders
```

I used Northwind and I will write the normal query

```
SELECT c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName, p.ProductName,s.CompanyName 
FROM Categories c 
INNER JOIN Products p ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.SupplierId = p.CategoryId
```

Comment: what is special about the result? Possible answer might be adding DISTINCT in your query

Comment: If you know Northwind database 1st and 4th results are category and they dont have product name and supplier company

Comment: So, what is the problem? your query looks good. It returns the data you expected. You have mentioned about GROUP in subject of your question but I don't see any track of grouping in your result.

Comment: Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: It is not solution becase all records are referenced if you know Northwind database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get needed results with that query:

```
SELECT c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName, p.ProductName,s.CompanyName 
FROM Categories c 
LEFT JOIN Products p ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Suppliers s ON s.SupplierId = p.SupplierID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName, NULL, NULL 
FROM Categories c 
ORDER BY CategoryId, ProductName
```